# insertAfter Repeating Elements

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, e-commerce, insertafter

I am building an eCommerce site on a CMS where the Product Names are on top of the Image. I would like to move the Product Name below the Image.

I am using:

```
$( ".productListNames" ).insertAfter( ".productListImageContainer" );
```

The problem though, is that it takes every .productListNames element and puts them under the .productListImageContainer on every single product.

How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to apply this logic to each item. The products probably all have their own container:

```
$('.container-of-every-item').each(function () {
    var $container = $(this);
    $container.find('.productListName').insertAfter($container.find('.productListImageContainer'));
});
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hm...thanks for the quick response! It actually isn't working...not sure why the selector wouldn't work...

Each Product has it's own container...but doesn't have a class...

They are li's in the ul class "productListGroupContainer" inside the div id "productImages". ".productListGroupContainer li" doesn't seem to work for ".container-of-every-time".